# Logo in Netbeans Toolbar

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-platform

I have a simple question which I couldn't find out how to implement it with the help of the search engines on the Internet.

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1 as a RCP for the project I am working on. Netbeans provides a Toolbar which is quiet neat in terms of easy modification via XML-Layer files to add actions and shortcuts to functionalities.

However I have to integrate a logo inside the Toolbar which should be as high as the buttons which are displayed but it shouldn't be a button.
How can I achieve this? Is there any way to directly insert code in the used toolbar class file? If so which file would that be?
Otherwise how to manipulate the XML file? Or is there a different way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
cheers,
Thor

Comment: If it were a button, what would it do?

Comment: If toolbar configured from xml, I think you can create a dynamic menu as it can be configured in eclipse rcp with help of(plugin.xml). Dynamic menu can returns what do you want. Try to find it in docs for NetBeans.